# Have a sequence $a_{n}$ and want to find exact $n$ for a prescribed result

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $a_n = \frac{2^n}{14n}$ and want to find $n$ for a result $\frac{4096}{49}$. I dont have clue what adjustment to make, but I know I have to start by this $a_n =\frac{4096}{49}$. 
Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If it's an integer, $n$ must be of the form $2^a \cdot 7^b$.

Comment: Cool, but I would prefer some exact process, not just quessing. :)

Comment: Pearls before swine, Robert. Pearls before swine...

Comment: I have no clue, tried already some calculations on my paper.

I know what I have to find, but dont know how to get there. I only need solution to this one and learn steps which I can use to similar assesments in the future.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{4096}{49} = 2^{\ldots} \cdot 7^{\ldots}$.